# Endpoint /users/{userId}/drive/recent returns empty array

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I've registered my app in Azure Portal and gave all authorizations required for using endpoint `/v1.0/users/{userEmail}/drive/recent`

I am calling it from a Node.js script, authenticating using package `adal-node`, using method `authContext.acquireTokenWithClientCertificate(...)` to retrieve the auth token.

This worked well for months, but by end of july '18 the endpoint started to return unexpected results:

**Starting august '18, its results were "out of date".**
For example, when a user created a file in his OneDrive root directory, it did not show up in the endpoint results anymore (most recent results were dated near end of may).

**Today, the endpoint returns an empty array.**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": []
}
```

When trying the same endpoint on Microsoft Graph Explorer, it behaves as expected (either `/me/drive/recent` or `/users/{userEmail}/drive/recent`).

Tried with `/beta` from my app, no luck.

Is this endpoint still supported? Are there other endpoints allowing an app to retrieve files created / modified recently by a specific user (for SharePoint & OneDrive)?

Versions:

- Node.js 6.9.5
- adal-node 0.1.22

Comment: This sounds like a possible issue with your tenant. I would open up a support ticket from the O365 portal so someone can dig into exactly where the issue lives. If it turns out to be an API or SDK issue, they'll be able to route it to the  correct team.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thanks for your reply ; ticket is opened.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I've got this reply: _"Graph API is not a supported platform for the Office365 Concierge support team"_ and I'm redirected to https://microsoft.com/en-us/solution-providers/home but this page does not allow to create a support request about Graph API.
Searching from the menus, the best I can get is the Graph API support page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support which tells to ask for questions on... StackOverflow :) 
Is there any other way to reach a tech support about this kind of issue?

Comment: I've added some tags that might help pop this on someone's radar. You may want to try opening the ticket through Azure. Graph spans a _lot_ of orgs but ever workload goes through the AAD/Identity folks on the Azure side (Graph itself is an API agrigator and that agrigator project is Azure).

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I noticed that when I decoded the token from the app, it did not have the permissions that I granted on Azure. Why is that? How can I solve it? Any idea?